# Determining constant in a CDF

Tags: probability-theory, self-learning, statistical-inference

I have a question that I literally have no idea how to begin, I was hoping someone could help me:

1. It says $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ is a sample from a distribution
2. It says that the Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF) is

$$F(x,\theta) = 1 - C/((x-\theta)+3)^4,\quad x > 0, \theta > 0$$

The instructions now say

> determine the constant C (no computation required) and determine the
>   pdf f(x).

Can anyone point me in a direction of a resource? or give me a hint as to how to get started? I have no clue what this distribution function is at all!

Comment: The parameter $\theta$ has to be $\le 3$. Otherwise we do not have a cdf on $(0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $F(x,\theta) = 1-\frac{C}{((x-\theta)+3)^4}$ is a cumulative distribution function, then we know that it must satisfy certain properties, namely:

1. $F(x,\theta) \to 0$ as $x\to -\infty$;
2. $F(x,\theta) \to 1$ as $x\to \infty$;
3. $\frac{dF}{dx} \ge 0\ \forall x$.

The probability density function is simply $\frac{dF}{dx}$, by definition. To find the constant $C$, we need only look at the first few properties. Hint: for any arbitrary choice of $\theta$, what does $\frac{1}{((x-\theta)+3)^4}$ look like?

Comment: If $\theta = 4$ and $x=1$, then $F$ is undefined unless $C=0$. But if $C=0$ then property 1 cannot hold. What am I missing?

Comment: @JasonZimba where did theta=4 and x=1 come from? Why couldn't it be C=1, since x is a realization of a random variable and could be anything in the support?

Comment: Sorry if my comment was not on point - I am not an expert on probability theory. But just reading the question, it seems to say that $F(x,\theta)$ is a function of two variables, where the two variables must both be positive. Well, 1 and 4 are both positive. So shouldn't I be able to evaluate $F$ at those values?

Comment: @JasonZimba Your first point says that $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are sampled from the distribution. This tells me that the random variable is $x$, not $\theta$. Instead, $\theta$ is a parameterization of the distribution. This is common. So you don't really have a two-variable distribution, but rather a univariate one with a parameter $\theta$.

Comment: @Arkamis is this a pareto?? Because it doesn't look like any of the forms here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution#Pareto_types_I.E2.80.93IV

Comment: @Arkamis Thanks, and I really don't mean to slow the discussion down. But is $\theta = 4$ an allowable parameter value? If so, then for that parameter value, doesn't the graph have a gigantic singularity at $x = 1$?

Comment: @Gosset Probably not; there's no reason I would suspect it to be.

Comment: @JasonZimba Yes, it would have a singularity wherever $x = \theta - 3$. But then it wouldn't be a CDF. So, there must be conditions on $\theta$ that avoid this condition. We're *given* that it's a CDF, so you can assume that $\theta$ implicitly meets these restrictions.

Comment: OK, then I think we need $\theta \leq 3$. I was just confused because the constraint given by OP is $\theta > 0$.

Comment: @JasonZimba It's just forcing you to think a little bit. There are *two* constraints on $\theta$: $\theta > 0$ which is enumerated explicitly, and $\theta \le 3$, which is implicit given that we're given $F$ as a valid CDF.

Comment: I would call it sloppy, personally.

Comment: I don't know. I think it induced you to ask a very good, natural question and to think carefully about the problem and the definitions.

Comment: I respect your view. I do think you're giving the person who wrote the question a lot of credit....

Comment: More domain confusion. In your reply, you stated a condition for $x\rightarrow -\infty$. But isn't the CDF only defined for $x > 0$?

Comment: Yes, so effectively the condition $F \to 0$ as $x \to -\infty$ can be replaced with $F \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ and $F = 0$ for $x \le 0$. These latter conditions obviously satisfy the former.

Comment: For what it's worth, although this may seem like needless generalization, it actually makes sense when you begin to look at probability theory in a measure-theoretic sense. Having these general definitions allows us to write theorems without having to consider a bevy of special cases.

Answer (score 0):

Let $F(x,\theta)$ be defined for $x>0$ and $\theta < 3$ by $$F(x,\theta) = 1 - {C\over(x-\theta+3)^4}\,.$$ If $F$ is a CDF in $x\in (0, \infty)$, then what must be the value of $C$?

Well, as $x\rightarrow 0$ from the right we have $$F(x,\theta)\rightarrow 1 - {C\over (3-\theta)^4}\ .$$
For $F$ to be a CDF, this limit must be zero, so that $C = (3-\theta)^4$.

That makes $$F(x,\theta) = 1 - {(3-\theta)^4\over(x + (3-\theta))^4}\,.$$

Note that $F\rightarrow 1$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$, as required for a CDF. It can also be verified that ${\partial f\over\partial x} \geq 0$.

Comment: I just want to thank everyone who contributed to this answer, it has been most instructive. I was looking at this problem in an incorrect manner, attempting to identify some kind of common distribution, when I should've been considering this as an algebraic issue. Thanks again, all.